# Get last value from \tikzsetnextfilename

Tags: tikz-pgf

I regularly use the pattern

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzsetnextfilename{<SOME-NAME>}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \subimport{.}{figures/<SOME-NAME>.tex}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:<SOME-NAME>}
\end{figure}
```

It so happens, that I forget to change the label `fig:<SOME-NAME>` when copy-pasting this code around. That's why I wondered, if there is the possibility to retrieve the value set with `\tikzsetnextfilename` so that

```
\label{fig:<SOME-NAME>}
```

could be changed to

```
\label{fig:\tikzgetnextfilename}
```

For a different use-case I would also like to get the value of `\tikzsetexternalprefix` for the import command.

EDIT: I extended my use-case in the sense that I would like to also use the variable to import the correct file.

EDIT2: I ended up using

```
\providecommand{\tikzfile}{}

...

\begin{figure}                                         
    \renewcommand{\tikzfile}{<SOME-NAME>}       
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\tikzfile}                    
    \centering                                         
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                
        \subimport{.}{figures/\tikzfile.tex}           
    \end{tikzpicture}%                                 
    \caption{This is the figure with name \tikzfile.}% 
    \label{fig:\tikzfile}%                             
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `\tikzsetnextfilename` is very simple, it is defined as

```
\gdef\tikzexternal@nextfile{#1}
```

meaning that the filename will be stored in the (global) macro `\tikzexternal@nextfile`. You can use this macro for your labels, however it contains an `@` symbol (indicating that it is an internal macro) which means you can only use it in your own code if you switch off the special meaning of `@` temporarily with the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` macros. This is very inconvenient for the current use case, therefore it is easier to change the original definition in order to create two macros, the original `\tikzexternal@nextfile` with the `@` symbol and another custom macro without the `@` symbol that can be used in `\label`.

MWE, based on the TikZ manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
% main document, called main.tex
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\makeatletter
\def\tikzsetnextfilename#1{\gdef\tikzexternal@nextfile{#1}\gdef\mytikznext{#1}}
\makeatother
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzext/] % activate
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzsetnextfilename{trees}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A tree}
\label{fig:\mytikznext}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzsetnextfilename{gridlines}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A grid}
\label{fig:\mytikznext}
\end{figure}

\centering See Figure \ref{fig:trees} and \ref{fig:gridlines}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ty for your answer. Based on it I thought the following two things should work. But neither did:
1.) print out the desired value to the document with
`\makeatletter\the\tikzexternal@nextfile\makeatother`
2.)  define my own setter and getter with
`\newcommand{\settizkfile}[1]{\tikzsetnextfilename{#1}\renewcommand{\gettikzfile{#1}}`

Can you explain why both ideas are not working?

Comment: For the first: 1. you don't need `\the` and 2. the value is reset at some point by TikZ, probably by `\end{tikzpicture}`, so you cannot use the macro after that. For the second: you forgot a `}` after `\gettikzfile` (the syntax is `\renewcommand{command name}{definition}`, so here `\renewcommand{\gettikzfile}{#1}`. Moreover in order to use `\renewcommand` you need to have `\newcommand` somewhere before that, so `\newcommand{\gettikzfile}{\relax} \newcommand{\settikzfile[1]{...}` works.